# How can I use two keys with defaultdict?

Tags: python, django, defaultdict

I am trying to create a defaultdict with nested keys. Here is the view that I wrote, but apparently multiple keys don't work in defaultdict.

```
def routine_view(request, klass_id):
    days = Routine.DAYS
    periods = Routine.PERIODS

    class_details = defaultdict(list)
    classes = Routine.objects.filter(klass_id=klass_id)

    for cls in classes:
        class_details[cls.day][cls.period].append(cls)

    context = {
        "days": days,
        "periods": periods,
        "class_details": class_details
    }
    return render(request, "routine/routine_view.html", context)
```

When I run this view I get the following error:

```
IndexError at /routine/1/
list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't totally clear, but I think you want a defaultdict which itself contains a defaultdict of lists. So:

```
class_details = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

Alternatively, you may not need a nested dict at all; you could instead use the original defauldict with key that is a tuple:

```
class_details[(cls.day, cls.period)].append(cls)
```

Comment: I am trying to make a routine for a class. So the first key is the day (sun, mon, etc.) and the second key is the period (first, second, etc.). In my template I am trying to access data for each period like this `{{ class_details.day.period }}` by looping through the `class_details` variable.

Comment: I have used the code you have provided, the template doesn't show anything.

Comment: But that is a completely different question, which has been answered many times here before: in a Django template, `class_details.day` will always refer to the literal key "day".